# How to plot different line style for each column in the dataset using seaborn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have the following dataset `df`:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   5   6   9  
7   9   10  11  13
6   10  11  23  87
```

I want to create a seaborn line plot so that for each of the columns I get a different linestyle with the same color, the linestyle which I can choose, however, I am clueless about how to proceed from here

I tried this and I am getting the required result however I want to choose the different linestyle for each of the columns manually:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `markers` to activate multiple linestyles, and use `palette` to set all columns to the same color:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, markers=True, palette=['blue'] * df.columns.size)
```

[image]

This example uses `markers=True` which lets seaborn automatically choose the linestyles, but you can also pass a list of [matplotlib markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html) to manually specify your own:

> `markers` : boolean, list, or dictionary
>
> Object determining how to draw the markers for different levels of the style variable. Setting to `True` will use default markers, or you can pass a list of markers or a dictionary mapping levels of the style variable to markers. Setting to `False` will draw marker-less lines. Markers are specified as in matplotlib.